# AngularJS form validity within controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

From what I know, the $valid property (and other similar ones) are accessible with $scope.formname.inputname.$valid from the controller..

I've played around with this: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/oEfdMpI3URooJhRFfSUr?p=preview

```
this.validity = $scope.myForm.input.$valid; //ADDED THIS LINE
```

Why does this one line that I added in script.js break it? I would expect {{ctrl.validity}} to show up as true.

Answer (score 0):

You added that line in a controller's constructor.

By the time that the constructor instance is created, the form in a view hasn't been compiled yet.

Try using `$timeout` to defer the execution of the line like this to make it works:

```
var ctrl = this;

$timeout(function () {
  ctrl.validity = $scope.myForm.input.$valid; //ADDED THIS LINE
});
```

Or if you want to keep them in sync, use `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('myForm.input.$valid', function (isValid) {
  ctrl.validity = isValid;
});
```

Hope this helps.